# roslaunch pi_tracker tracker

Tags: roslaunch, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI, all. I encounter a problem when roslaunch pi_tracker tracker.launch as follows. I set use_real_robot: False, but why it still requires Serial port?

... logging to /home/nutan/.ros/log/5ffee514-5133-11e0-b054-00e081b5d370/roslaunch-nutan-desktop-6166.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://nutan-desktop:45340/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/left_foot
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_knee
- /tracker_joint_controller/max_rotation_speed
- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/right_knee
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_shoulder
- /tracker_joint_controller/reverse_rotation
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_foot
- /tracker_base_controller/scale_drive_speed
- /tracker_base_controller/holonomic
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/neck
- /tracker_joint_controller/holonomic
- /tracker_command/default_joint_speed
- /tracker_joint_controller/joint_controller_rate
- /tracker_base_controller/scale_rotation_speed
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_shoulder
- /tracker_joint_controller/fixed_frame
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_shoulder
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/torso
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_hip
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_hand
- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/torso
- /tracker_joint_controller/command_rate
- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/left_elbow
- /robotis_joint_controller/baud
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/neck
- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/right_foot
- /tracker_command/max_drive_speed
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/torso
- /tracker_command/scale_drive_speed
- /tracker_base_controller/max_drive_speed
- /tracker_command/base_controller_rate
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_shoulder
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_hip
- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/right_hand
- /robotis_joint_controller/rate
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_foot
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_elbow
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_knee
- /tracker_base_controller/use_real_robot
- /tracker_command/reverse_rotation
- /tracker_joint_controller/scale_rotation_speed
- /tracker_base_controller/base_controller_rate
- /tracker_base_controller/tracking_rate
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_elbow
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/head
- /tracker_joint_controller/max_drive_speed
- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/head
- /tracker_command/fixed_frame
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_hand
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_hip
- /tracker_command/tracking_rate
- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/right_shoulder
- /tracker_base_controller/reverse_rotation
- /tracker_command/command_rate
- /tracker_base_controller/default_joint_speed
- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/left_shoulder
- /tracker_base_controller/base_control_side
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_elbow
- /tracker_joint_controller/default_joint_speed
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_knee
- /tracker_command/use_real_robot
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_elbow
- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/left_hip
- /tracker_joint_controller/use_real_robot
- /tracker_command/joint_controller_rate
- /tracker_base_controller/command_rate
- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/right_hip
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/head
- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/neck
- /tracker_base_controller/fixed_frame
- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/left_knee
- /tracker_joint_controller/base_controller_rate
- /tracker_command/max_rotation_speed
- /tracker_command/holonomic
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_hand
- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/right_elbow
- /robotis_joint_controller/port
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_hip
- /tracker_command/scale_rotation_speed
- /tracker_command/base_control_side
- /tracker_joint_controller/base_control_side
- /tracker_base_controller/joint_controller_rate
- /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/left_hand
- /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_knee
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_foot
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_foot
- /tracker_base_controller/max_rotation_speed
- /tracker_joint_controller/scale_drive_speed
- /tracker_joint_controller/tracking_rate
- /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_hand

NODES
/
tracker_command (pi_tracker/tracker_command.py)
tracker_base_controller (pi_tracker/tracker_base_controller.py)
tracker_joint_controller (pi_tracker/tracker_joint_controller.py)
robotis_joint_controller (pi_tracker/robotis_joint_controller.py)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://nutan-desktop:11311/

core service [/rosout] found
process[tracker_command-1]: started with pid [6185]
process[tracker_base_controller-2]: started with pid [6186]
process[tracker_joint_controller-3]: started with pid [6187]
process[robotis_joint_controller-4]: started with pid [6188]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nutan/pi/pi_tracker/bin/robotis_joint_controller.py", line 103, in 
jc = joint_controller()
File "/home/nutan/pi/pi_tracker/bin/robotis_joint_controller.py", line 58, in **init**
usb2dynamixel = USB2Dynamixel_Device(self.port)
File "/home/nutan/pi/robotis/src/robotis/lib_robotis.py", line 54, in **init**
self._open_serial( baudrate )
File "/home/nutan/pi/robotis/src/robotis/lib_robotis.py", line 86, in _open_serial
raise RuntimeError('lib_robotis: Serial port not found!\n')
RuntimeError: lib_robotis: Serial port not found!

[INFO] 1300435773.701176: Shutting down joint command controller node...
[INFO] 1300435773.706859: Initializing Tracker Command Node...
[INFO] 1300435773.712698: Initializing Base Controller Node...
[INFO] 1300435773.726363: Initializing Joint Controller Node...
[robotis_joint_controller-4] process has died [pid 6188, exit code 1].
log files: /home/nutan/.ros/log/5ffee514-5133-11e0-b054-00e081b5d370/robotis_joint_controller-4*.log

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9472/roslaunch-pi_tracker-tracker/) by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jie Sky](https://answers.ros.org/users/20509/jie-sky/) on 2015-06-25**:
Hello,Mar.Did you realize that  gestures control your robot by pi_tracker？ Can you tell me how to do it?Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry about that.  At some point I added the robotis joint controller directly to the launch file.  To fix, remove the robotis include line from your tracker.launch file so that it looks like this:

```
<launch>
    <node name="tracker_command" pkg="pi_tracker" type="tracker_command.py" output="screen">
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find pi_tracker)/params/tracker_params.yaml" />
    </node>
    
    <node name="tracker_base_controller" pkg="pi_tracker" type="tracker_base_controller.py" output="screen">
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find pi_tracker)/params/tracker_params.yaml" />
    </node>
    
    <node name="tracker_joint_controller" pkg="pi_tracker" type="tracker_joint_controller.py" output="screen">
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find pi_tracker)/params/tracker_params.yaml" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

I've also updated this in the SVN repository.

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on 2011-03-20**:
Thanks, patrick